# Trying to load a Jquery v3 google map, works inside body tags, but not where i want it on the page

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I call a javascript function in the header with the body onload() command:

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" id="page1" onLoad="load()">
```

It calls the javascript load() function to load a map into a div "map":

```
function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}

  });
```

Here is the div just inside the body tag:

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
```

This works fine, map loads up and is dispayed. But if i put this div inside another div, so it will load where i want it on the page, it acts like it is loading a map but, I cant see it. like in this code below:

```
  <div id="content">        
            <div class="indent-main">
                 <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="indent-col2">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-5">
                                     <div class="block">
                                        <div class="indent-block">
                                           <select class="jamp3">
<option>-----Select a State -----</option>
                                              <option>Alabama</option>

                                              <option>Wyoming</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"> <div class="block1">
                                        <div class="indent-block">

                                        </div></div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flash">
                              <div id="map" style="width: 100%;  height:80%"></div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-3 maxheight">
                                <div class="box2 maxheight">
                                    <div class="border-top maxheight">
                                        <div class="border-bottom maxheight">
                                            <div class="border-right maxheight">
                                                <div class="border-left maxheight">
                                           <div class="corner-top-right maxheight">
                                          <div class="corner-top-left maxheight">
                                        <div class="corner-bottom-left maxheight">
                <div class="corner-bottom-right maxheight">  
                <div class="indent-box">
                <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="link-3"><em><b>learn more</b></em></a>
                </div>
                                   </div>
                </div>
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
```

It doesnt matter where I put the div "map", other than right inside the body tags, it will not show up on the page.

Her is a link to the broken page:
[Broken Page](http://techmonsters.com/index_real_map.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25)

Comment: Please supply a link to the broken page, or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Map is there...look down at bottom

Comment: I know but, I want it to show up above the two boxes in the center. like in the code above.

Comment: want me to reposition the div to the spot where i want it?

Comment: There i moved it to where i want it to go.

Comment: exactly, now it is no longer visible after i relocated the div "map" to where i want it to show up on the page

Comment: Is there some kind on DOM listener, or maybe this div is loading behind another div.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using relative (percentage) sizes, and the browser has no reference to base them on. Try changing the percentages to absolute pixel dimensions temporarily and see what happens. To use percentages, every element which contains the map must have a size specified, all the way up to "html". You can use your style sheet to do that: I guess that the percentages are percentages of the screen size, so all the containing elements need width:100%;height:100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the map if you scroll down.  I checked it with both IE and Chrome.

UPDATE:  It appears the website you link to has changed - it is no longer visible.

Comment: exactly, now it is no longer visible after i relocated the div "map" to where i want it to show up on the page

Comment: i have sat here all weekend trying to figure this out. Need a whiz for this one